# How to batch rename files using loop combination in bash?

Tags: bash, rename

I have 2 folder structure like this:

```
SOURCE_FOLDER_W_GOOD_NAMES
├── A_some_name.png
├── B_another_different_name.png
├── C_just_another_too.png
└── D_this_one_stop_this_example.png
```

Another folder:

```
DESTINATION_FOLDER_W_INCREMENT_NAMES
├── icon_0.icns
├── icon_1.icns
├── icon_2.icns
└── icon_3.icns
```

So basically, `SOURCE_FOLDER` already contains the files which are sorted in alphabetical order. This sort order is already matched with `DESTINATION_FOLDER` (eg: `A_some_name.png` === `icon_0.icns`)

I'm using this loop combination to rename the files:

```
i=0
j=0
for img in SOURCE_FOLDER/*.png; do
  for i in {0..10000}; do
    let j++ || true;
    mv "SOURCE_FOLDER/icon_$i.icns" "DESTINATION_FOLDER/${img%.*}.icns"
  done
done
```

I executed this on the command line (the above is formatted, I'm a one-liner guy) in the root of the above folder.

```
THE_FATHER_FOLDER
├── SOURCE_FOLDER_W_GOOD_NAMES
└── DESTINATION_FOLDER_W_INCREMENT_NAMES
```

Unfortunately, the above loop is not working as I expected. I'm certain that I'm wrong but I don't know where.

Please correct me.

## UPDATED

Solution for the above question, I solved it myself

```
counter=0
for img in SOURCE_FOLDER/*.png; do
  let counter++ || true;
  mv "SOURCE_FOLDER/icon_$counter.icns" "DESTINATION_FOLDER/${img%.*}.icns"
done
```

But I have another question, in this folder:

```
DESTINATION_FOLDER_W_INCREMENT_NAMES
├── icon_0.icns
├── icon_1.icns
├── icon_2.icns
└── icon_3.icns
```

I want to reindex it from **1** instead of **0**, thus I'm using this:

```
counter=0
for index in {0..final_number}; do
  let counter++ || true;
  mv "icon_${index}.icns" "icon_${counter}.icns";
done
```

At the moment, my files are started from **0** and ended up by **final_number - 1**, so it will overwrite every single-file I have in this folder and I got only the first file (icon_0) which renamed to (icon_final_number) when it's done.

How could I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to do the rename *backwards*:

```
counter=$((final_number + 1))
for index in {final_number..0}; do
  mv "icon_${index}.icns" "icon_${counter}.icns";
  let counter--;
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm certain that I'm wrong about algorithm. You save my day.

Answer (score 1):

Your problems will be solved by the following code:

```
#!/bin/sh

i=0
for img in `ls SOURCE_FOLDER_W_GOOD_NAMES/*.png`; do
        mv $img DESTINATION_FOLDER_W_INCREMENT_NAMES/icon_$i.icns
        i=$((i+1));
done
```

Comment: Thank for your opt-in but I already resolved it in my way. Please check the question, I have a new one :)

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your counter with the value 1 instead of 0,
and increase it after a move is done. Then you won't need to run a secondary bash script just for renaming the files, you would address it in the original script.

Also, why when you increase your counter you add " || true" ? it has no meaning.
Try this code

```
counter=1
for img in SOURCE_FOLDER/*.png; do
  mv "SOURCE_FOLDER/icon_$counter.icns" "DESTINATION_FOLDER/${img%.*}.icns"
  let counter++
done
```

Comment: You don't understand, the secondary bash script will be executed firstly. And I need to use it in another place with same logic. I already solved and posted solution of the first one, why you post the solution of first one too?

Comment: I misunderstood you. try this then

`counter=1;
for index in {0..final_number}; do
  mv "icon_${index}.icns" "icon_${counter}.icns";
  let counter++;
done`

Comment: This will not work also, please read the question carefully. It will overwrite everything in that folder and return you only one file after this loop done.

Comment: Please specify what you want to be returned. As it seems, this loop will rename all the files in the folder, but I don't see any return action or what you expect to be returned in your question

Comment: Yes it will rename all files but it will OVERWRITE EVERYFILE till the loop done. Finally, you will only get ONLY ONE file. And as I said, please read the question carefully.

Comment: Excuse me for not understanding what you are trying to do here. I don't understand what you mean "you will only get ONLY ONE file". Where do you get a file here? the loop itself just renames files, not returning anything to the caller.
I'll let someone else figure it out. Goodluck.

Comment: Do you understand when I said will overwrite everyfile in that folder? Then why you don't understand the phase "I will only get only one file"? Btw, anything returns something.

Comment: Ofcourse it will rename every file in that folder. I'll make it easier, let's break down the algorithm of what you wrote:
1. Create a loop from 0 -> FINAL_NUMBER
2. Increase the counter by 1
3. Execute mv "icon_${index}.icns" "icon_${counter}.icns";

That's it. This either going to return 0 or 1, in case the mv operation had failed.

Comment: I think we can stop the conversation from now, Vinny. I found the correct solution and algorithm. Thanks for your opt-in anyway :)